# Hudson : Builds Taking Longer time than What it takes by running it Locally

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hudson, build-automation, jenkins

I found a unusual behavior on Hudson.
The Hudson jobs take around 25 minutes , where as when I run the same job locally, it takes 9 minutes.
What I'm missing here?

I increased the JAVA_OPTS, MAVEN_OPTS and even gave the server more memory to start with.
The machine has 12 Gigs of memory.

> -Xrs -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle
>   -jar "%BASE%\hudson.war" --httpPort=9090 --ajp13Port=9099

MAVEN_OPTS:

> C:>echo %MAVEN_OPTS%
>   -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

JAVA_OPTS:

> C:>echo %JAVA_OPTS%
>   -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m

Still the build takes 25 minutes.

Comment: Maybe the process of downloading the sources from your VCS is causing for the difference in time? Also, you might want to put a break up of timings, as in which step takes how much time on your machine and Hudson..

Comment: What version of maven are you running on your machine and your hudson machine (if not the same)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparing a local build on one system to the time it takes hudson to complete a build on a completely different system doesn't necessarily indicate any problems (maybe your local machine is a better machine than your build server?)

On your hudson server (maybe via SSH) run the mvn build and see how long it takes to run.

Then run the same build via hudson on that same system and see how long it takes to run.

Then you'd not be comparing two different machines.

Also, your hudson build could be doing a lot more than your normal build - for instance if you are asking it to start with a clean repository before the build it will be doing a whole lot of downloading for each build that your local machine wont have to do - especially if you don't have a cached maven repository server running on your local network.

Comment: +1 for the IO, we had the same issue and tracked it down to the "Archive build" feature, which copies the workspace from the slave to the hudson master via SSH, which was _very_ slow (unbuffered?)

Comment: +1 for the general approach. We had the similar issue and found that the build was way slower with java 6 compared to java 5. It is actually a java 6 bug but don't think that it will be fixed soon.